# How to store logged in user's information in "myprofile" named scene in javafx?

Tags: javafx

I have created login form and a "my profile" named scene. So when user logs in it changes to the "my profile scene" but the informations don't get updated. How to store the user data in the my profile scene?
I have used a user & user service class to store user information from which i can login. Now i want the logged in informations to be printed on "my profile" scene.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what exactly you need. Could you provide a minimal code sample and/or extended use case description?

Answer (score 0):

```
package Profile;

 import carrentalservice.CarRentalService;
 import carrentalservice.Customer;
 import carrentalservice.CustomerService;
 import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
 import javafx.event.EventHandler;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.scene.control.Label;
 import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
 import javafx.geometry.Insets;
 import javafx.geometry.Pos;
 import javafx.scene.control.Button;
 import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
 import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
 import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Profile extends Scene {

Label MyProfileLabel;
Label UserIDLabel;
Label NameLabel;
Label GenderLabel;
Label LocationLabel;
TextField UserIDTextField;
TextField NameTextField;
TextField GenderTextField;
TextField LocationTextField;

static VBox root = new VBox(10);

public Profile(){

    super(root,500,350);





            MyProfileLabel=new Label("My Profile");
            MyProfileLabel.setId("label-custom");
            UserIDLabel=new Label("ID");
            NameLabel=new Label("Name");
            GenderLabel=new Label("Gender");
            LocationLabel=new Label("Location");

            UserIDTextField=new TextField();
            UserIDTextField.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
            UserIDTextField.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);




            NameTextField=new TextField();
            NameTextField.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
            NameTextField.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);

            GenderTextField=new TextField();
            GenderTextField.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
            GenderTextField.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);

            LocationTextField=new TextField();
            LocationTextField.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
            LocationTextField.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);


    root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    root.getChildren().addAll(MyProfileLabel,UserIDLabel,UserIDTextField,NameLabel,NameTextField,GenderLabel,GenderTextField,LocationLabel,LocationTextField);
            root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            root.getStylesheets().add("ProViper.css");   







}
```

}

Comment: here is what i did but i  have zero idea how to create a profile that would show the info of user who logged in